# Getting the error message -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: terminal

I am trying to enter the command to open a specific file on my desktop. The file has one closing parentheses in it, after a 0. How do I get around this? I will attach a screenshot of the Terminal.

[Screenshot of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz5HL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the filename in double quotes like `open "/foo/bar (0).pdf"`

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of the error message, but didn't open the file. I copied the pathname, pasted it into Terminal and it worked. A backslash was needed after the 0 and before the ). So, instead of      .../Flow\ charts/0)\ BRE.....           it should have been      .../Flow\ charts/0\)\ BRE...         Thanks again though!